# configure openvpn client for only one interface

Tags: php, linux, curl, interface, openvpn

hell guys,
i'm trying to setup open vpn client to connect to tunnelbear vpn, and use it to do some anonymous requests in php with curl.

i'm doing that on a remote VPS, so if i do a mistake the vpn block me and i'm forced to reboot the vps.
actually my client config is like this :

```
client
dev tun0
proto udp
nobind
ns-cert-type server
persist-key
persist-tun
reneg-sec 0
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8
dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4
verb 3
auth-user-pass login.key
ca CACertificate.crt
cert UserCertificate.crt
key PrivateKey.key
remote fr.lazerpenguin.com 443
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
keysize 256
keepalive 10 30
script-security 2
```

i don't have any redirect gateway setup, because if i add it, my whole traffic go through the vpn and everything is blocked.
i just want to use the vpn for somes specials requests.

like :
whole traffic -> without vpn except for tun0 requests

i use this in php to use the vpn interface :
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "tun0");

but the traffic seems to don't use the vpn cause the public ip of the curl request is not anonymous.

i'm very lost with all theses routes settings help me please :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by using this "up" script :

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "$dev : $ifconfig_local -> $ifconfig_remote gw: $route_vpn_gateway"

ip route add default via $route_vpn_gateway dev $dev table 20
ip rule add from $ifconfig_local table 20
ip rule add to $route_vpn_gateway table 20
ip route flush cache

exit 0
```

and this client conf :

```
   client
dev tun0
proto udp
remote fr.lazerpenguin.com 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca CACertificate.crt
cert UserCertificate.crt
key PrivateKey.key
verb 5
route-method exe
route-delay 2
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
keysize 256
comp-lzo
auth-user-pass login.key
script-security 2
route-noexec
route-up vpn_up.sh
```

now if i set the interface to tun0 in curl it use openvpn and if not the classic network interface

Comment: I have the exact same need except I'm on windows, what tweaks do you think I need to adapt to have this working on windows? Specially the first quote.